# Default variables for colors in Bootstrap LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, mixing

I am using Bootstrap Less for some project, and I want to make it to change colors of css according to some variables. I have look up for this solution

http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/

This is great, but i have one problem, i dont know what are the names of those variables, that i can choose colors. please take a look at seven color that are generated.

All I need is seven less variables that Bootstrap using for color
like this one

```
@brand-primary;
@brand-success;
@brand-warning;
@brand-danger;
@brand-info;
```

Can someone tell me the names for those seven variables from example link i send?

I mean just names of variables that are using those colors

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for here...

Comment: Do you mean the colors or the name of the variables themselves?

Comment: I mean just names of variables that are using those colors

Comment: I also don't understand.  The variables are defined in `variables.less`.

Comment: Yes ok in variables, but what are the name of those seven variables i need?

Comment: Any additional comments on my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables you're looking for are (in the order they're listed on LavishBootstrap):

```
@body-bg
@gray-lighter
@gray-light
@gray
@brand-primary
@table-border-color
@navbar-inverse-bg
```

Comment: No I need those seven :(

Comment: For now i think it is great just to check

Comment: @Schneider If I helped, please upvote/accept.  If I can improve, let me know.

Comment: @Schneider bro... you havent heard? SomeKittens is a SO hacker who preys on people who copy and paste answers without learning what they do and how they do it. I'm afraid you're about 46.5 hours away from a CPU crash if you run this code. (That's a joke. C+P answers isn't what we strive for here. Please learn when you ask! And SomeKittens is a great man :D )